# Cannot set the initial location of documents navigator using Storage Access Framework (SAF)

Tags: android

The documentation says "Callers can set a document URI through `EXTRA_INITIAL_URI` to indicate the initial location of documents navigator."

But it won't resolve `EXTRA_INITIAL_URI` here. I tried setting the constant given for this as shown in the comment (`EXTRA_INITIAL_URI = "android.provider.extra.INITIAL_URI"`), but that does not work. How do I get it to resolve?

```
package com.ship.saftwo;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import java.io.File;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {navigateToAppDirectory();}});}

    private static final int READ_REQUEST_CODE = 42;
    // adding this does not help: public static final String EXTRA_INITIAL_URI = "android.provider.extra.INITIAL_URI";

    public void navigateToAppDirectory() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + File.separator + getResources().getString(R.string.app_name) + File.separator);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent.setType("*/*");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, uri);
        //error message: Cannot resolve symbol 'EXTRA_INITIAL_URI'
        startActivityForResult(intent, READ_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find the solution ??

Comment: Did you find the solution ? If yes, please share it.

Comment: @Perseus https://stackoverflow.com/a/67553040/9846650

Comment: This might help you - https://stackoverflow.com/a/67553040/9846650

Answer (score 21):

From [DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/DocumentsContract.html#EXTRA_INITIAL_URI):

> Location should specify a document URI or a tree URI with document ID. If this URI identifies a non-directory, document navigator will attempt to use the parent of the document as the initial location.

As far as I'm aware

- You cannot specify a starting location using an arbitrary URI, e.g. `Uri.fromFile`, it needs to originate from a DocumentsProvider
- You cannot specify a starting location on API 25 and below

Assuming `uri` was retrieved from [Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE):

```
DocumentFile file = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(context, uri);
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, file.getUri());
```

Comment: how did you know that you cannot use an arbitrary uri and it had to originate from DocumentsProvider?

Comment: There is no need to use a DocumentFile, uri = DocumentsContract.buildDocumentUriUsingTree(uri, DocumentsContract.getTreeDocumentId(uri))

Comment: can you please add the code how exactly we can get the Uri?

Comment: Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3ADocuments");

Answer (score 1):

I was able to set it like this :

```
    private fun requestUri() {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT)
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
        .setType("application/text")
        .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "DEST_FILE_NAME")
        .putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)
    requestUri.launch(intent) // my start activity for result logic 
}
```

```
private var requestUri = registerForActivityResult(StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
    if (result != null && result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        result.data?.let { intent ->
            intent.data?.let { fileUri ->
               // u have a valid uri now 
            } ?: run {
               // show some error Ui
            }
        }
    }
}
```

in my app i can set DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI to something like :

- Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS
- Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS

may this help some one :)

Comment: I've tried this solution but it doesn't work on Android Emulator API 30 Pixel_3a. It cannot set the initial location (folder).
It also show ClassCastException in log:
    W/Bundle: Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
    java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to android.os.Parcelable.
Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS is a String. It may not be used as a URI (Parcelable)

Comment: Doesn't work on real device (Android 11) or emulator (Android 13). It just opens the last chosen path.